# Extra vertical space after frame in document class {book} when a image not fit on the page

Tags: document-classes

I create a two side document for a book. When I insert a image  after some text and frame that not fit on the page, the text between frame and image starts in bottom of  the page and created extra vertical space. But if I use for example the command \documentclass{report} this problem solved and the text starts immediately after frame no vertical space. How do I use the command ‎\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}  does not create a vertical distance? This is the document:

```
 %‎‎‎\documentclass[11pt]{report}‎‎
‎\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book} ‎
‎\usepackage[a4paper‎,
‎landscape‎,
‎top=3cm,headsep=10pt‎,
‎textwidth=15cm‎,
‎right=3cm‎,
 ‎outermargin=7cm‎,
    ‎marginparwidth=5cm‎,
       ‎marginparsep=10pt]{geometry} 
‎\usepackage{color}‎‎‎
‎\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}‎
‎\usepackage{mdframed}‎
‎\usepackage{fancyhdr}‎  

‎\usepackage{graphicx}
‎\usepackage{color}‎
‎\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}                     ‎ ‎‎
‎\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt‎,
‎skipbelow=7pt‎,
‎rightline=false‎,
‎leftline=true‎,
‎topline=false‎,
‎bottomline=true‎,
‎backgroundcolor=black!5‎,
‎linecolor=red‎,
‎innerleftmargin=5pt‎,
‎innerrightmargin=5pt‎,
‎innertopmargin=5pt‎,
‎leftmargin=0cm‎,
‎rightmargin=0cm‎,
‎roundcorner=0mm‎,
‎linewidth=2pt‎,
‎innerbottommargin=5pt]{dbox}‎
\begin{document}‎‎‎
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
\begin{dbox}
‏some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
‎‏\end{dbox}‎‎‎‎
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
‎\begin{center}‎
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
   ‎\end{center}‎ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\raggedbottom` in the preamble. `book` calss uses `\flushbottom` by default.

Comment: Thank you very much.  can generally change the command \flushbottom to \raggedbottom once and for all?As a newenvironment or newcommand?

Comment: Just put `\raggedbottom` say, before `\begin{document}` like `\raggedbottom\begin{document}`